# canvas automatic pixel blending/transitioning feature

Tags: javascript, html, animation, graphics, canvas

I noticed that some of the canvas2d methods seem to have a feature that was surprising to me. In particular, the `context.lineTo(x, y)` and `context.drawImg(imgObj, x, y)` methods. I would have thought the x,y coordinates would be taken only in integers, but something special seems to happen if I give them as a float - the browser seems to magically adjust the color of the pixels on the edges of the graphical components to paint them "in between" the 2 discrete neighboring pixels coordinates.

For example, lets say my stroke color is black, and then I call `context.lineTo(100.2, 0)`. I'll get a nice black line the goes to x coordinate 100, but the pixel at coordinate 101 is also painted, but it's painted a shade of grey that seems to correspond with the fractional part of the x coordinate(eg a darker grey for `context.lineTo(100.4, 0)`)

#### [I made a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYEjZ/1/)

where I animate both images and lines to demonstrate the effect visually. In both cases, the lower image and lower line were animated by passing floating point arguments to the canvas methods - and you can see how they're very smooth due the browser doing its magic. The line effect is difficult to see at high monitor resolutions, but it's there. The image is impressive because it doesn't just blend the edges, it seems to be fully aware of transparency.

opera, firefox, and chrome all seem to do it.

**My questions:**
Is this documented in any browsers/spec?
Is there a term for this?

I want to call this some form of anti-aliasing or interpolation, but I don't think either of these terms are correct for this. I want know what it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most canvas systems, the one of HTML5 is based on **float coordinates**. And rounded coordinates are **between** screen pixels.

This means that aliasing has to occur, in order to better fit pixels you put over more than one "real pixel".

This is a very important thing to know, as it lead to fuzzier and wider lines, depending on the position of the line. On the following picture, both lines have a `lineWidth` of 1 but the first one is drawed at `y=1` while the second one is drawed at `y=4.5`:

[image]

See [this post I wrote on this problem](http://canop.org/blog/?p=220) where I give 2 functions I made as an example of a way to deal with it (I use similar functions for rectangles too). More generally, you have to take into account the line width but the logic should be clear using the picture : to have sharp shapes, try to fill the real screen pixels.

Drawing images at not integer coordinates smooths the image, which is rarely the desired effect, and also brings a performance penalty, as interpolation has to occur. You generally should draw your images, when they're at screen scale, only on rounded coordinates, both for performances and for fidelity to original.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the coords were float based. However, this doesn't address any of my questions. It only confirms my observations that the browser adjusts the "greyness" of the edge pixels depending on how far off the coordinates are from a discrete coordinate. How does it work for images? by adjusting the transparency level of each pixel based on the same psuedo distance? "aliasing" is the most correct term for this?

Comment: Aliasing is the correct term : the border pixels take an intermediate color, which is practically equivalent to having a transparency level. If you draw an image at rounded coordinates, this doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on that canvas feature too much though, it can slow things down: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/#toc-avoid-float

Comment: interesting. that links call this feature "sub pixel rendering"